# why to use separate string constants file?

Tags: java

Given the way String pool works for a given piece of code why is it preferred to create a separate file for storing the constants?

```
String str = "test";
```

Suppose, the String "test" is used over 50 times in the entire application. Why is recommended to store this in a constants file. Now ,the way string pool works should actually create only one object if it doesn't exist in the pool and then share the references of this object to other places as and when needed. Then why to create a separate constant file to store constants?

Comment: Because it makes it easier to change it later, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major importance comes with internationalisation, having a strings file means you have a few places in which you have to search for translatable text.

Consider the case when your app becomes a hit and it's being shipped outside of the locale in which it was developed, with a unified strings file, you just have to do a simple conversion of the file content, while with other methods you will have to search every single file and replace every single instance before your application is barely usable to people in different locales.

A very good example is the android resource system for strings. If you keep strings in specific files, it's easier managing them and translating them.

Comment: I think this reduction to I18N isn't really the driving thing. That aspect exists, but there are for sure other reasons as well.

Answer (score 2):

Following advantages you get

- Code duplication is avoided across the project. The defined string is constant across the project and can be reused in multiple places
- If user want to modify the string value across the codebase, he/she has to change only one place in the file.
- Strings don’t clutter up your project code, leaving it clear and easy to maintain
- If you want to support localization/i18 support in other languages, then it will be highly useful. Putting strings in resource files makes it much easier to provide separate translations of each string for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: because code duplication is the root of all evil.

Constants are less about performance than about maintaining an application in the long run. As soon as some "property" is used with the same *meaning* in different places - you want to make sure that all usages are based on the very same definition. So that when updates are necessary, only one line of code needs to be adapted. And not 50, with an ever growing chance of missing to update one or the other occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You need some storage for this literals (not only file and etc.) for simple reasons: if you need to change the value of this literal, then you will change it only in one place. For this reasons exists 2 main solutions:

1. use constant class with `public static final Object CONSTANT` fields.
2. use external storage (for example, file)

First case has 2 problems: at first, if you change this values, you will need to recompile project. at second, if this variables used by some frameworks you need to pass this arguments directly in your code. Also, when you need to support of i18n, you could obtain problems with managing right variants.

But when you use external storages, only what you need is implement parser for your storage (I mean json, xml, db and so on). Some frameworks already implement this feature, so you don't need to make this work.

Howevere, you mustn't do it, but it's just really good practice.

Answer (score 0):

That is because if anyone want to make changes in this string in future, then you don't need to search it in whole project. Just make changes in **constants file**.

Answer (score -1):

Because everything has its place and there's a place for everything. If it's a constant string that, hopefully, will never change and it's used application-wide then logic dictates it (and things like it) should be defined separately for both maintenance and code readability concerns.